# Acrescentar Letra num campo com 20000 linhas

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Tenho uma tabela `produto` preenchida com 20000 produtos e preciso de acrescentar um `o` no primeiro caracter do campo `codigo` de todas as linhas.

Como posso fazer isso com MySQL?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não é claro o que você está a perguntar. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Quer acrescentar um "O" num campo da tabela? Ou num ficheiro? Qual é a ligação com mysql?

Comment: é simples tenho 20000 referencias todas com o seu codigo diferente 1000 1001 1002 e quero renumerar para o1000 o10001 o10002 assim suscivamente que é para separar referencias antigas de referencias novas

Comment: @AndreFrancisco Você tagueou a pergunta com `mysql` e `insert`, levando as pessoas a pensar que isso é uma pergunta sobre banco de dados... É isso, ou é um arquivo (ficheiro) de texto? Ou outra coisa? E finalmente: que linguagem de programação você está usando?

Comment: mas é um banco de dados mysql é uma tabela que tenho códigos de produto que preciso de renumera-los com uma letra a esquerda preciso da instruçao para o insert dessa letra

Comment: Então não é um ficheiro como diz na pergunta é uma tabela, certo?

Comment: sim e uma tabela chamada produto em que o tenho o campo codigo quero acrescentar uma letra nos registos todos! peço desculpa ainda sou um bocado noob nisto

Comment: @AndreFrancisco veja a minha edição e se é isso que queres perguntar.

Comment: E ISSO MESMO OBRIGADO

Comment: Qual é o tipo deste campo?

Comment: O código do produto é *Foreign Key* em alguma tabela?

Answer (score 3):

Considerando que a coluna é de tipo texto, e que essa alteração não causará efeitos colaterais danosos (como quebra de chaves estrangeiras), o comando é simples:

```
UPDATE produto
SET codigo = CONCAT('o', codigo);
```

Como na pergunta existem as incógnitas que mencionei acima, recomendo fazer um backup da base de dados antes de executar isso.